# How to turn on you PC via Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot

Is there a way to automatically power on my machine?

I've searched for something like this over google, but I've found something related to BIOS stuff, related to RTC alarm.

The thing is that on my laptop, I do not have something like that incorporated in my BIOS.

Is there any other way of doing this given the fact that I am running Windows 7 OS on my PC?

Comment: there are 2 options to automate turning on a computer but not all computers support either of them.  1) via a set clock time 2) sending a wake-on-lan signal.

Comment: @MrSlayer thanks for enlightening me about the power button, if it weren't your comment, I wouldn't know about it. :)                       AlanBarber : can you give me more details regarding the clock time and how to program it? The thing is that my computer is not connected with any LAN so I cannot apply wake-on-lan.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your computer on Hibernate, you could try to "turn it on" via built-in Task Scheduler in Windows 7.

```
Start > Control Panel > System and Security > Administrative Tools > Task Scheduler
Action > Create Basic Task
Create Basic Task Wizard > fill in the title and description there
Task Trigger > set up triggers
Action Screen > Start a program > Next
Program/script > "C:\Windows\System32\winresume.exe"
Confirm/Next/Finish w/e till the end
```

That's the best I know.

Comment: `winresume` isn't a normal Windows program and thus cannot be started by the Task Scheduler (which is suspended when in Hibernate anyway)

Comment: @Joey: you can tell the task scheduler to wake the system for a particular task, if you've configured your power settings to allow wake timers.  (Granted, it doesn't make sense to select winresume.exe as the program to run.)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [WOL or Wake on LAN](http://www.smallnetbuilder.com/lanwan/lanwan-howto/29941-how-to-wake-on-lan-wake-on-wan). This does require that your hardware support it, a lot of hardware surprisingly does.

It also has to be sent within the network.